# UML diagram for a MySQL database whose tables are independent from each other

Tags: mysql

I've been given an existing database to model as part of a side project. However I noticed that none of the tables are related to each other. Has anyone come across this problem before? If so could you recommend a way to model the database.

Thanks

Comment: are you asking about uml diagramming ?

Comment: @DavidChan yes UML diagrams.

Comment: I don't get it... Doesn't that just make the job easier?

Comment: do you mean you are trying to automatically generate a class diagram from the db and and you get classes with no associations?

Comment: @jurgenreza no i'm trying to manually create a class diagram but there are no relationships, i thought the whole point of modelling the database is to see how the classes interact with each other. Is it possible to have a UML diagram with no links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML has many diagrams, I think what you mean is a class diagram used for data modeling (Data modeling class diagrams are like entity relationship diagrams (ERD). They are used to model the database tables).

Assuming that is the case, yes it is possible for a class diagram to have no relationships. Basically you show classes with their attributes and operations. When modeling database tables however, there are no operations; so you end up with classes (tables) and attributes (columns).

Other details you could include in your diagram are the attribute (column) types and the constraints (primary key etc.).